# Javascript - How do I override default action when user presses play/pause from mobile notification controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm putting together a website for live-streaming audio. It uses an html audio element and some custom javascript / jquery controls to stop buffer and change buttons on pause.

On Android when playing audio from chrome a play-pause button appears in notifications. Similarly iOS devices have media controls outside the browser.

When a user presses those controls the play-pause command is sent directly to the audio element (bypassing the controls I set up.)

How do I intercept these commands and make them call my custom functions instead?

My play control launches this function:

```
function startAudio () {
  // add number to get var to force fresh load each time
  i++;
  $("#audioPlayer").attr("src",source + "&nocache=" + i).trigger("play");
  $("#playpause").removeClass('playing paused').addClass('loading');
  audioPaused = false;
}
```

I tried:

```
audioElem.onplay = function() {
startAudio()
}
```

but as you would expect, this just causes an infinite loop since play is called within startAudio().

For context: on pause the audio source is removed to prevent continuous loading of the live stream while paused. When starting again, a new load is forced by adding a number to the source url (that increments each time). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play and pause events are here for you.

```
audioElement.onplay = function() {
    /* trigger your customs controls */
};
audioElement.onpause = function() {
    /* trigger your customs controls */
};
```

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_pause.asp

Comment: For jquery would that be $("#myaudio")[0].on('play', function(){ ... }) ?

Comment: Yes, but no need for jQuery here. jQuery uses a compatibility event management for IE.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve my problem because my play control alters the src before play so if I call that function it creates an infinite loop. Please see code I added to the question.

Comment: Actually just decided to restructure the entire script. On pause: remove source, on play: if no source add one then try again. Ultimately that will Eliminate the need to intercept play/pause events.